# How to detect in a jailbreak tweak AVCaptureSession start and get which app started it?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, avcapturesession, tweak, theos

Basically, I want to know when a user is presented the camera feed and from which app this was triggered.

I tried to hook in `AVCaptureSession`'s `-(void)startRunning;`

but

`SBApplication *topApp = [(SpringBoard *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication];`

is not working. It turns out that calling `sharedApplication` returns `null`. I've also tried calling the method on `%c(SpringBoard)` or `objc_getClass("SpringBoard")` but had the same result.

Besides this, the hook works only when opening the camera in the Messages app, although I specified in the Filters dictionary several bundles like `com.apple.springboard`, `com.facebook.Facebook` etc.

What am I doing wrong? Isn't `AVCaptureSession` API used by other apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SpringBoard class only exists in the SpringBoard process therefore `%c(SpringBoard)` or `objc_getClass("SpringBoard")` will return nil on any other process.

To get the current bundle name of the applications you are hooking, you can use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]`. You'd have to use some form of IPC/XPC to send this information as well as additional information regarding the session that you want to know about. The receiving end could be either the SpringBoard process or a personal daemon so as to not clog SpringBoard with additional tasks.

As for your question "Isn't `AVCaptureSession` API used by other apps ?", it is possible that some applications use other classes to capture images/video rendering this hook useless. As a jailbreak developer I have found, as many others, that Apple programmers don't adhere to a strict coding style. There can also be other lower level functions that achieve the same purpose, in which case you would have more work to do as there is no class-dump parallel to C functions.

Comment: Can you point me in a direction to look for those lower level functions? Or are they application/developer specific? Even so, there are so many apps that can use other API for video rendering that I think I hit a dead end, or a bad compromise.

Comment: Sure, for the lower level functions you can use tools like nm and otool (See more information in http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Reverse_Engineering_Tools).

As I've seen creker's answer, he also mentioned IPC in the form of notifications. We both say this (at least I think we do) is because this way you can know when AVCaptureSession is used as soon as that method is called. Using files would involve polling, which wastes cpu cycles.

As for dead end, there never is really one. There is plenty of resources from where to get information and where to get in contact with other developers.

Comment: @uroboro, polling is one way of doing it (periodically checking for changes wouldn't waste much cpu). You could also use `kqueue` to monitor file/directory changes without polling.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing would be to load your hook into every application. To achieve that you could use `com.apple.UIKit` as bundle filter. That way your hook will be loaded into every application where you would hook `AVCaptureSession -(void)startRunning` or `UIImagePickerController` methods to detect camera usage.

The problem with this - you have to implement some IPC mechanism to send notifications with user info from within sandboxed application. I don't know of any IPC API that could send those. Distributed notifications can't send user info with notifications from sandboxed app - it must be empty. Darwin notification center doesn't support user info. CFMessagePort also doesn't work. May be XPC does but I didn't tried it.

One possible solution is to find directory where even sandboxed app has write permissions (http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Seatbelt). That way you could create a file in that directory with some data and send Darwin notification to your, let's say, daemon that will be observing these notifications. This daemon then will find the file and read the data you "attached" to your notification.

As for "lower level functions" to access camera. Basically, there are two ways you could access camera - `AVCaptureSession` and `UIImagePickerController`. Those are the only public APIs available for AppStore apps. If we are talking about cydia apps/tweaks, I don't think anyone would bother when you have AVFoundation APIs.

Comment: There are some things that are unclear. Can't the hook in `AVCaptureSession` just write to a file to say "Hey camera used by `com.xyz.bundle`? Why would I need notifications? Also, filtering with `com.apple.UIKit` doesn't solve anything (for now). As before, I tried to write to a file in `-(void)startRunning` but only when I open the camera in the Messages app it actually writes. This is why I need some IPC mechanism, for the other apps from the AppStore ?

Comment: I assumed you need to know right away when an app starts to use camera. If you just want to log `startRunning` calls then of course you could just write it to a file. `com.apple.UIKit` filter should load your tweak into every application that has UI (better also add `com.apple.avfoundation` filter in case of a daemon). Why it doesn't work I don't know. At least, `startRunning` can be hooked, I tested it. To test whether your hook works use `NSLog` instead of file writes and look in the console. Sandbox may deny your file writes.